# Jquery code to set default name in dropdown list

Tags: jquery

Am using following code to display following values in dropdownlist

```
function getServerList() {

  $.getJSON('/getlidst', function (data) {
    var html = '';
    data = data.reverse();
    data.forEach(function (n) {
console.log(n.url)
      html += '<option value="' + n.url + '">' + n.url + '</option>';
    });
    $('#server').html(html);
  });
}
```

here console.log prints following values.ice my `dropdown` list contians following values

```
testsite
highsjiteover.com_default
twoclever.com
172.16.7.80_default
172.16.2.18
```

what i want is from the above values the topmost string with default is set as default in dropdown

also i want to set the dropdown value with out appending the `default` string ie`(highsjiteover.com)`  not `highsjiteover.com_default.`

How it is possible?

Comment: Be aware that **maybe** for some browsers, appending `options` inside `select` element by using `.html()` method may not work as expected. I suggest you test this in each major browsers if it cares.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data.forEach(function (n) {
  console.log(n.url);
  var url = n.url.indexOf('_default') > -1 ? n.url.split('_')[0] : n.url;
  html += '<option value="' + url + '">' + url + '</option>';
});
```

as per your comment you can add this after your loop:

```
$('#server').find('[value*="highsjiteover.com"]').prop('selected', true);
```

---

`var url` to set the value we are using a ternary operation here. We have to check for the `_default` if this is available then we will split that string by `_` to create an array of that string and we return the `[0]` index which holds the url without `_default` and if there is no `_default` is available then we are returning the `n.url`.

Comment: ok thats fine but how can i set top string with defualt as default in dropdown list(ie in my list i want to set the top string highsjiteover.com_default as set default value in dropdown )

Comment: @Sush you can add this after your forEach loop: `$('#server').find('[value*="highsjiteover.com"]').prop('selected', true);`.

Comment: not thay way ur harcording hat values it may change

Comment: Actually you don't need to do this because first option is always get selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is for making the first `option` that contains *default* as the `select` menu's default value. Put this after JSON operations inside the function.

```
 $("select#server option[value$=default]").first().attr("selected" ,true);
```

Comment: Edited. check again please